# how to disable button before before any element is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Can we disable buttons "next" and "previous" until user select any element of tree view.

In other words, user should select one of the element from tree view 
then it should select next and previous button but before that they are disabled?

I am using tree view in my example.

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/72/)

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    if($('.jstree-clicked').closest('li').next().length)
        $('.jstree-clicked').removeClass('jstree-clicked').closest('li').next().find('a:eq(0)').addClass('jstree-clicked')

});
 $('#pre').click(function () {
     if($('.jstree-clicked').closest('li').prev().length)
        $('.jstree-clicked').removeClass('jstree-clicked').closest('li').prev().find('a:eq(0)').addClass('jstree-clicked')

});
```

Comment: your fiddle is not responding, i just clicked more that 10 times all around the page.. but nothing responds.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop)** to disable the buttons on page load:

```
$('#next,#pre').prop('disabled',true);
```

and re-enable it when your element is selected:

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    $('#next,#pre').prop('disabled',false);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/73/)**

Comment: can you please look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556861/how-to-validate-forum-using-dforum-js-and-validate-js

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following statement inside the dom ready event.

```
$('#next,#pre').attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$('#next,#pre').prop('disabled',true);
```

Bind the following event so that once the user has selected any one of the element, it will be enabled

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    $('#next,#pre').prop('disabled',false);
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

First put `disabled="true"` for both button in html

```
<button id="next" disabled="true">next</button>
<button id="pre" disabled="true">pre</button>
```

then on select event of tree remove `disabled` attribute from buttons

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    alert("node_children: " + data.node.children);
    $('#tree').jstree(true).toggle_node(data.node); 
$('#next, #pre').removeAttr("disabled");                                                       

 });
```

here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/75/)

Comment: please look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556861/how-to-validate-forum-using-dforum-js-and-validate-js

Answer (score 0):

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalsc/fuu94/74/)

The simplest solution is probably just to disable the buttons when the page loads. Then just re-enable them once a user clicks an element in the tree:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ADDED
    $('button').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    alert("node_children: " + data.node.children);
    $('#tree').jstree(true).toggle_node(data.node);
    // ADDED
    $('button').removeAttr("disabled");  
});
```